# SVN checkout running slow via LAN

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu, svn, svnserve

I have a small LAN at home connecting 2 computers with an switch and the switch to ADSL router. Small "server" running Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS and client running Windows XP.

The server runs:

```
svnserve -d --listen-port=6999 -r ./Repo1
```

for a small project (4 MB, ~200files).

**Whats the problem?** Running `checkout` on the client machine is **very slow** (when I mean *very* I mean I'm running the checkout now for like ~30min and I've got ~70% of the data in my local copy).

**I've tried...**

- turning the firewall OFF and ON and
  nothing changed
- changing the svn client (TortoiseSVN, Netbeans SVN plugin)
- configure `svnserve` to generate log files but no errors where there

The network connection is ok no package loss on the way from/to the machines.

**What can I try more? Any suggestions would be great!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about anti-virus?  Not so much on the server, but the clients.  AV can really tank a Subversion checkout.

Comment: Seems not like this, but thanks for the answer, propably it will help for someone.